# Mini PCIe WiFi/Bluetooth adapter for Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, pci-express, windows-10, broadcom

I'm having difficulty getting an ASUS Mini PCIe WiFi/Bluetooth adapter working in Windows 10 (x64), not sure what the model of the card is but it is using a Broadcom bcm4352 chipset. I can't find a Windows 10 driver for the device so I'm wondering if anyone can help me find a driver that works with the chipset or can recommend a Mini PCIe WiFi/Bluetooth adapter that is compatible with Windows 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After reading around online some seem to suggest it may be to do with Cisco VPN client interfering with things. I was unable to uninstall the client as it came up with an error message so I chose to reset the PC/do a fresh install of Windows 10 and the WiFi/Bluetooth is now working.

Comment: I had a similar issue on my Lenovo Yoga and re-imaging fixed the it.